# PosrgreSQL Pivot Table

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, pivot-table

I need to make a PIVOT table from Source like this table

```
FactID  UserID  QTY Product
1         10    100   A
2         10    200   B
3         10    300   C
4         12    50    A
5         12    60    B
6         12    70    C
7         15    500   A
8         15    550   B
9         15    600   C
```

Need Pivot Like this

```
UserID  A   B   C
10     100  200 300
12     50   60  70
15     500  550 600
```

My try

```
Select UserID,
       CASE WHEN product = 'A' then QTY end as A,
       CASE WHEN product = 'B' then QTY end as B,
       CASE WHEN product = 'C' then QTY end as C
from public.table
```

And Result

```
UserID  A   B   C
10     100  100 100
10     200  200 200
10     300  300 300
12      50  50  50
12      60  60  60
12      70  70  70
15      500 500 500
15     550  550 550
15     600  600 600
```

Where's my mistake? Maybe there's another way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very close.  You just need aggregation:

```
Select UserID,
       SUM(CASE WHEN product = 'A' then QTY end) as A,
       SUM(CASE WHEN product = 'B' then QTY end) as B,
       SUM(CASE WHEN product = 'C' then QTY end) as C
from public.table
group by UserId;
```

In Postgres, though, this would normally use the `FILTER` clause instead of `CASE`:

```
Select UserID,
       SUM(qty) FILTER (WHERE product = 'A') as A,
       SUM(qty) FILTER (WHERE product = 'B') as B,
       SUM(qty) FILTER (WHERE product = 'C') as C
from public.table
group by UserId;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need aggregate function as

```
Select UserID,
       Max(CASE WHEN product = 'A' then QTY end) as A,
       Max(CASE WHEN product = 'B' then QTY end) as B,
       Max(CASE WHEN product = 'C' then QTY end) as C
from public.table
Group by userid
```